# retrofit 2.0b2 : How to get InputStream from the response?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 2.0b2. After getting a response, I tried getting an InputStream from the response by :

```
Response<JsonNode> response = call.execute();
InputStream is = response.raw().body().byteStream();
```

but the app keep throwing :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.
        at retrofit.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody.source(OkHttpCall.java:184)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.byteStream(ResponseBody.java:43)
        at ...
```

Despite the response returned correctly. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: well clearly the problem is that you are getting a response by type of `JsonNode`, rather than something that doesn't get auto-converted (because auto-converting reads it from the stream and nothing remains for the byte stream). Try `Response<Void>`?

Comment: Tried, nope. Still failed whether it is 'JsonNode' or 'Void' or 'Object'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want the raw stream, tell retrofit to return an OkHttp `ResponseBody`.

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Response;

Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();
try ( ResponseBody responseBody = response.body() ) {
    InputStream is = responseBody.byteStream();
    // ...
}
```

Remember to update your interface, too.

[As the response body is backed by a limited resource, the `responseBody` object must be closed after usage](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html). Therefore  above code uses a *try-with-resources* statement.

Comment: Thanks @iagreen , Your answer is absolutely correct. I had a hard time finding the right way to convert the `ResponseBody` to a raw json to go ahead with my work. Thank you =)