# how to get the raw response in retrofit2 instead of POJO

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 for all the network calls in my android application. Im configuring a POJO for a particular response. But I want to just check the raw Json repsonse for some extra response which is not included as a variable in POJO.

POJO

```
public class User {

  @SerializedName("user_id")
  private long userId;

  @SerializedName("user_name")
  private String userName;

  @SerializedName("hobbies")
  private String hobbies;

  @SerializedName("class")
  private String studyClass;

  @SerializedName("branch_id")
  private long branchId;

  @SerializedName("createdOn")
  private Date createdOn;
}
```

My network interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

  @GET("user/{userId}")
  Call<User> getUserInfo(@Path("userId") long userId);
}
```

My code for requesting the data .

```
if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
ApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<User> call = apiService.getUserInfo(userId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            User user = response.body();
            setViews(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On failure while requesting server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

How to check the raw response . But I want the interface method to return the POJO.

Comment: Instead of @Get() just try calling getUserId(Id)  and then String rawJson = api.getUserId(Id).toString();

Comment: Do you mean ``response.raw().body().string()``?

Comment: @Fred I tried that code , it is not working

Comment: but why is it not working? It's not what you want? do you get an exception? If you do this and ``response.body()`` on the same object, it won't work AFAIK

Comment: @Fred response.raw().body().string() -> this code is not working

Comment: try @aldok's response here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088975/how-to-get-raw-response-and-request-using-retrofit-2-0